# Atribuir valor recebido via ajax a uma variável

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
var idArtigo = $(".codigo", this).text();
            myJSRoutes.controllers.ArtigoDocumentoController.getArtigoByDebitoTipo(parseInt(idArtigo)).ajax({
                success: function (data) {
                    if(data == true){
                        console.log("O ARTIGO_ID"+idArtigo+" tem debito manual");
                       artigosDebitoManual.push(parseInt(idArtigo));
                    }
                }
            });

function testeStateDebito(retorno){
            var state;
            $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
                if(artigosDebitoManual.length > 0){
                    state = true;
                }else{
                    state = false;
                }
                retorno(state);
            });
        }
```

Como posso atribuir esse "retorno" a uma variável para usar "fora" do pedido ajax?

Tenho desta forma:

```
testeStateDebito(function(cont) {
            console.log(cont);
            return cont;
        });
```

O `console.log` retorna-me true ou false, mas eu gostava de ter esse estado numa variável, do género: `var estado = 'valor retornado';`

Como posso resolver isto?

Comment: O que quer dizer com o fazendo a requisição? Eu estou a usar o $(document).ajaxStop(function() {...}) para gerir os valores que recebo só no fim de todas as requisições ajax

Answer (score 2):

Você pode pegar o valor obtido via ajax dessa forma:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'exemplo/consulta',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (dados) {
        var resultado = dados;
    },
    error: function () {

    }
});
```

Comment: Como posso adaptar isso à função que eu tenho? Só quero retornar o 'state' conforme está na minha função"

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi direito o que você deseja fazer. Você faz uma consulta que te retorna os artigos certo? E dependendo do retorno de artigos você quer retornar "true" ou "false"?!

```
var estado;

var artigosDebitoManual = ['1', '2', '3'];


function testeStateDebito(retorno) {
    var state;

    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        if (artigosDebitoManual.length > 0) {
            state = true;
        } else {
            state = false;
        }
    });

    return state;
}

function teste() {
    estado = testeStateDebito();
    console.log(estado);
}
```

Comment: $(document).ajaxStop({
                success: function (dados) {
                       console.log("SUCESSO");
                }
            }); Isso dá-me erro : Uncaught TypeError: ((n.event.special[g.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || g.handler).apply is not a function ------ Eu estou a usar o ajaxStop não sei se tem influência.

Comment: Você poderia me mostrar seu código, pra eu entender melhor? 
Você já tem os valores do "artigosDebitoManual" ou busca ele via Ajax?

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei antes os pedidos ajax que estão dentro de um ciclo each, daí ter usado o $(document).ajaxStop para guardar os valores que quero no fim dos pedidos serem feitos, pois funciona de forma assincrona.

Comment: Eu editei a resposta acima. Conforme eu entendi seu problema é só onde jogar o retorno. Se você criar uma variável estado fora da sua função e atribuir que ela é igual ao retorno da sua função, você já terá o valor nos outros lugares.

Dê uma olhada no código dessa resposta e vê se te ajuda.

Comment: Compreendeu perfeitamente o que eu queria. Testei o seu código mas o console.log(estado) retorna undefined. O problema é esse. Desde já obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: A variável state fora do pedido ajax, e talvez por ser um pedido assincrono, não recebe o true ou false das condições.

Answer (score -3):

Uma variável declarada com var na função fica sendo privada, já com o this fica púbica.